# Please help me solve this complex integral.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$$\oint_C \frac{\cos(z-a)}{(z-a)}\mathrm{d}z$$

Such that $a\in \Bbb R^2$ and $C$ is a single closed curved defined by $|z-a|=\frac{|a|}{2}$

Here $z=x+iy$ is a complex number. Please solve the above integral. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried calculating the residue at the simple pole $z=a$ and using the Cauchy Residue Theorem?

Comment: Cauchy's integral forumla is enough (no need for the residue theorem).

Comment: A more difficult question: can our over-eager answerers hold off until "user" comes back and responds to the hint.

Comment: @GEdgar: Guess not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $$f(z) = \cos(z - a)$$

Then you use the Cauchy Integral Formula:

$$f(z_0) = \frac1{2 \pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)}dz$$

Let $z_0 = a$. Therefore this becomes:

$$f(a)=\frac1{2 \pi i}\oint_C \frac{\cos(z-a)}{(z-a)}dz = \cos(a-a) = \cos(0) = 1$$

Rearranging for your integral:

$$\oint_C \frac{\cos(z-a)}{(z-a)}dz = 2 \pi i \cos(0) = 2 \pi i$$